# LWC Publishing events with data from child to parent

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm developing LWC component which allows user to select files, and then passes data (base64) to parent component. I wonder which solution will be more efficient and optimal: pass all data (might be megabytes) in one event, or pass every file in separate event?

Please share your opinions and experience.

Answer (score 1):

As far as JS is concerned, it does not really matter. However, it might be more efficient to send each file as it is read so that whatever you're doing with those files can start earlier, since it can handle each file as it is read.